# Interface on ASA 5525 cannot turn up/up

Tags: cisco-asa, interface

The interface is connected to a switch and has the `no shutdown` command applied. The interface at the switch is already up/up, but ASA's interface is still down/down. Another ASA also has the same behavior. What is the reason for this?

Comment: Have you replaced the cable?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign name for the interface, like below example :
Configure t
Interface gigaethernet 0/0
 Name inside 
 Security-level 100

Answer (score 1):

Configure below commands in the Interface that you want to bring up

> nameif inside